# Load data from Hive to mongo subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive

I have a hive table which I want to load into mongo. 
I added the necessary hadoop-mongo jars and I created my mongo table as below:

```
CREATE TABLE mongo_tab
( subscribers STRUCT
<
persons_data: STRUCT
<last_name: string, 
first_name: string >                              
contracts_persons:STRUCT
<product_infos: STRUCT <product_id: INT, product_name: STRING>,
captial: STRUCT <capital1: string, capital2: string >
>,
employees: STRUCT 
< n_emp: INT, 
nom_emp: string>
>
)
STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES      ('mongo.columns.mapping'='{"last_name":"last_name", "first_name":"first_name","product_id":"product_id, "product_name": "product_name", "capital1":"capital1", "capital2": "capital2", "n_emp":"n_emp", "nom_emp":"nom_emp"},
}')
```

TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'=my_mongo_server_uri')

When I insert the data stored in hive table  into my mongo table , I get this error: 
"Cannot insert into target table because column number/types are different".

My questions are:

- Is it possible to load data from a hive table to mongo using subdocuments in mongo schema?  or it has to be a flat document ?
- How can I move my data given that I want to avoid a flat document structure in mongo?

Thanks in advance for your answer.